# Why is my JTextField in JFrame not working?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jtextfield

Simple question. I've been trying to block/disable my textfield in my JFrame, but unfortunately it just doesn't work!

Suppose the name of my disable textfield is "fnTxt", so in the code I wrote `fnTxt.setEnabled(false);`. And when I run it, nothing happen! The textfield is still able to be click/fill.

Am I doing it wrong or it's something else?

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: `setEnabled(false)` works for me.  Post an mcve as requested.

Answer (score 0):

setEnabled works fine for what it is meant for.
But I assume you want to make it invisible, for that you simple have to use `fnTxt.setVisible(false);`

Comment: Not invisible but disabled so the user can't type in their key word

Comment: For that setEnabled works fine. What did you have done? Maybe you should post some code